# I want to convert A json into another Json using JOLT transformation

Tags: json, jolt

I have the below JSON input, and I want to remove the **value** tag and set the **Title** value in **TypeOfSTA**.
I want to use JOLT transformation to convert in output JSON.

Below is my request JSON and output JSON.

**Request JSON:**

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "TypeOfSTA": {
        "Title": "ashish"
      },
      "EndDate": "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z",
      "IGACode": "175",
      "StartDate": "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z",
      "STATenure": "12",
      "TenureUnit": "Month",
      "TotalAmount": "5000",
      "EmpEmailID": "employee175@test.com"
    },
    {
      "TypeOfSTA": {
        "Title": "Rajan"
      },
      "EndDate": "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z",
      "IGACode": "175",
      "StartDate": "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z",
      "STATenure": "12",
      "TenureUnit": "Month",
      "TotalAmount": "5000",
      "EmpEmailID": "employee175@test.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me to transform using JOLT transformation.

output JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "TypeOfSTA": "ashish"
    "EndDate": "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z",
    "IGACode": "175",
    "StartDate": "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z",
    "STATenure": "12",
    "TenureUnit": "Month",
    "TotalAmount": "5000",
    "EmpEmailID": "employee175@test.com"
  },
  {
    "TypeOfSTA": "Rajan",    
    "EndDate": "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z",
    "IGACode": "175",
    "StartDate": "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z",
    "STATenure": "12",
    "TenureUnit": "Month",
    "TotalAmount": "5000",
    "EmpEmailID": "employee175@test.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***shift*** tranformation spec below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "TypeOfSTA": { "*": "&1" },
          "*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The asterisks denote the name of the outermost array(***value***), indexes of it, the index of ***TypeOfSTA*** object, and the rest of the keys existing within the array respectively.

The **&1** notation is used to go up and grab the value of the respective object's key.

The result screen from [**`Jolt Transform Demo`**](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) :
[image]

The result screen from **`Apache NiFi's JoltTransformJSON Processor`** :

[image]

**EDIT** : There was a single element for the ***value*** array within the previous case, in order to avoid the issues related to having multiple or single elements, eg. as a generic case just prepend each ampersand notation by `[&2]` and `[&1]` respectively such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "TypeOfSTA": { "*": "[&2].&1" },
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, Thanks for your help. I tried this JOLT specification but its not working..i am getting below output

Comment: {
  "TypeOfSTA" : [ "ashish", null ],
  "EndDate" : [ "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z", "2007-05-30T18:30:00Z" ],
  "IGACode" : [ "175", "175" ],
  "StartDate" : [ "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z", "2006-05-31T18:30:00Z" ],
  "STATenure" : [ "12", "12" ],
  "TenureUnit" : [ "Month", "Month" ],
  "TotalAmount" : [ "5000", "5000" ],
  "EmpEmailID" : [ "employee175@test.com", "employee175@test.com" ]
}

Comment: Hi @ashishmaurya I've added the related images in order to show the correctness.

Comment: Thanks So much Barbaros. Its working for single element but when I am using multiple element in Value tag its not working

Comment: @ashishmaurya Can you edit the question rather than adding comment by also adding the current input along with this result coming from multiple elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236677/discussion-between-ashish-maurya-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Comment: TypeofSTA key is  missing

Comment: Thanks So much Babaros .Now i am getting what I wanted